# python: adding data as string in mysql gives weird error

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having a weird problem with a piece of python code.

The idea how it should work:
1. a barcode is entered (now hardcode for the moment);
2. barcode is looked up in local mysqldb, if not found, the barcode is looked up via api from datakick, if it's not found there either, step 3
3. i want to add the barcode to my local mysqldatabase and request some input.

Now the problem: it works! als long as you fill in numbers for the `naamProduct`. If you use letters (eg. I filled in Bla as productname), I get a weird SQL-error `(_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'Bla' in 'field.list'")`

I have checked the tables in mysql and the types are all ok. The table where name should end up in is text. I have also tried a hardcoded string which works fine. Using the sql-query from the mysql console also works perfectly. My guess is something is going wrong with the inputpart, but I can't figure out what.

(code is still not really tidy with the exceptions, I know ;) Working on it step by step)

`

```
def barcodeFunctie(sql):
    con = mdb.connect ('localhost', 'python', 'python', 'stock')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    ver = cur.fetchone();
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    return ver

#barcode = '8710624957278'
#barcode = '2147483647'
barcode = '123'

#zoeken op barcode. Barcode is ook de sleutel in de tabel.
sql = "select * from Voorraad where Id=%s" % barcode

if barcodeFunctie(sql) == "None":
    print "geen output"
else:
    try:
            url='https://www.datakick.org/api/items/'+barcode
            data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
            print data['brand_name'], data['name']
    except:
            #barcode komt niet voor in eigen db en niet in db van datakick, in beide toevoegen
            print barcode, " barcode als input"

            naamProduct = str(raw_input("Wat is de naam van het product? "))
            hoeveelheidProduct = raw_input("Hoeveel inhoud heeft het product? ")

            sql = "insert into Voorraad (Id, NaamProduct,HoeveelHeidProduct) values (%s,%s,%s)" % (barcode, naamProduct, hoeveelheidProduct)
            barcodeFunctie(sql)
            print "meuktoegevoegd! :D"
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sql = "select * from Voorraad where Id=%s" % barcode
```

Your problem is that you are missing quotes for your ID. Change that line above to this:

```
sql = "select * from Voorraad where Id='%s'" % barcode
```

Comment: Ah should have seen that with that string doesn't work but int's do. Adding the quote fixed it, thanks for the help and your answer

Comment: You need to add quotes in your insert statement too. Refer to the answer by Chris.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you miss the single quotation mark for all your string placeholders. That would explain why it works with numbers but not with strings.

I didn't tested it, but in my opinion your SQL statement should look like:

```
sql = "insert into Voorraad (Id, NaamProduct,HoeveelHeidProduct) values ('%s','%s','%s')" % (barcode, naamProduct, hoeveelheidProduct)
```

Comment: jep, added the other quotation marks also after SSNR his answer. It works now. Thanks for the help.